# can't get the shared cookies from 1 node service to another node backend service using sessionstore

Tags: express, cookies, cors, session-cookies, credentials

i'm currently developing:

- (data distribution service) a backend service that can store and distribute data (product data, transaction data, etc);
- (credential service) a backend service that handles user credential

so here is the flow:

- user send credential data from client to the credential service
- credential service will save the token in the session and store it to the mysql sessionstore
- credential service will then response it with the credential data and save it in the client cookies
- after that if the user try to fetch data with the data distribution service, the data distribution service will try to fetch the saved session, i tried to fetch it using a simple req.session like the code below
- but the req.session.refreshTokens return null

1. this is the code in the data distribution service where i tried to fetch it and validate it

```
async function checkAuth(req, res, next) {
  // Check the user session
  if (!req.session) return res.sendStatus(401);
  if (!req.session.refreshTokens)
    return res.status(401).send(SESSION_TOKEN_NOT_FOUND);

  // Check the JWT in the header
  const authHeader = req.headers["authorization"];
  const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(" ")[1];
  if (token === null)
    return res.status(401).send(USER_UNAUTHORIZED);

  // Verify JWT access token
  jwt.verify(
    token,
    process.env.APP_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
    (err, user) => {
      if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
      if (!user.OTPVerified)
        return res.status(403).send(PLEASE_VERIFY_OTP);
      req.user = user;
      next();
    }
  );
}
```

2. this is the settings in the data distribution service

```
const AppConfig = (app, express) => {
  // Express app config
  app.locals.pluralize = require("pluralize");
  app.use(logger("dev"));
  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

  if (
    process.env.APP_STATE === PROD ||
    process.env.APP_STATE === PREPROD
  )
    app.set("trust proxy", 1);
  // CORS establishment
  app.use(
    cors({
      origin: CORSConfiguration(),
      credentials: true,
      optionsSuccessStatus: 200, // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
    })
  );

  // Tool to parse cookie
  app.use(cookieParser());

  // Establish session configuration
  app.use(
    session({
      secret: process.env.APP_SESSION_SECRET,
      name: "FOREFRONT-SESSION",
      cookie: {
        sameSite:
          process.env.APP_STATE === PROD ||
          process.env.APP_STATE === PREPROD
            ? "none"
            : false, // in order to response to both first-party and cross-site requests
        secure:
          process.env.APP_STATE === PROD ||
          process.env.APP_STATE === PREPROD, // it should set automatically to secure if is https.
        httpOnly:
          process.env.APP_STATE === PROD ||
          process.env.APP_STATE === PREPROD,
        maxAge: 3 * 60 * 60 * 1000
      },
      resave: false, // don't save session if unmodified
      rolling: true, // refresh the session max age on every response
      saveUninitialized: false,
      store: sequelizeSessionStore,
    })
  );
  // const csrfProtection = csrf({
  //     cookie: false,
  // });

  // Global Middleware
  app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(500).send("Something went wrong!");
  });
  // app.use(csrfProtection);

  return app;
};
```

3. this is the setting in the credential service (more or less the same as the data distribution service)

```
const AppConfig = (app, express) => {
  // Express app config
  app.locals.pluralize = require("pluralize");
  app.use(logger("dev"));
  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

  if (
    process.env.APP_STATE === PROD ||
    process.env.APP_STATE === PREPROD
  )
    app.set("trust proxy", 1);
  // CORS establishment
  app.use(
    cors({
      origin: CORSConfiguration(),
      credentials: true,
      optionsSuccessStatus: 200, // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
    })
  );

  // Tool to parse cookie
  app.use(cookieParser());

  // Establish session configuration
  app.use(
    session({
      secret: process.env.APP_SESSION_SECRET,
      name: "FOREFRONT-SESSION",
      cookie: {
        sameSite:
          process.env.APP_STATE === PROD ||
          process.env.APP_STATE === PREPROD
            ? "none"
            : false, // in order to response to both first-party and cross-site requests
        secure:
          process.env.APP_STATE === PROD ||
          process.env.APP_STATE === PREPROD, // it should set automatically to secure if is https.
        httpOnly:
          process.env.APP_STATE === PROD ||
          process.env.APP_STATE === PREPROD,
        maxAge: 3 * 60 * 60 * 1000
      },
      resave: false, // don't save session if unmodified
      rolling: true, // refresh the session max age on every response
      saveUninitialized: false,
      store: sequelizeSessionStore,
    })
  );
  // const csrfProtection = csrf({
  //     cookie: false,
  // });

  // Global Middleware
  app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(500).send("Something went wrong!");
  });
  // app.use(csrfProtection);

  return app;
};
```

AND THE QUESTIONS IS:

1.is there something wrong that i did so i can't seem to fetch the token?

2.do i need to xhr request the token to the credential service from the data distribution service to check the token?

TIA :)

Comment: i ended up using sid and attach it to my header from the client side, and then fetch the session from db using it, case closed